# How to modify while loop to print extra print statement in next loops? [java]

Tags: java, loops, methods, while-loop, switch-statement

These current `associationMenu` uses switch statements to implement methods corresponding to the `char` input by the user. The while statement loops over untill `X` is read.

I want to make some modifications such that when `X` is not the input.
It will print `"Please enter a number 1 or 2, or press X to exit."`
and run the method again.

```java
public void associationMenu(){
    char choice = readChoice();
    while (choice  != 'X' ){
        switch (choice) {
            case '1': exploreTeams(); break;
            case '2': newSeason(); break;
            default: associationMenu(); break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

```java
public char readChoice() {
    associationMenuHelp(); //prints first 4 lines of Sample I/O shown below
    System.out.print("Enter a choice: ");
    return In.nextChar();
}
```

Sample I/O

```
Welcome to the Association! Please make a selection from the menu:
1. Explore the teams.
2. Arrange a new season.
X. Exit the system.
Enter a choice: x
Please enter a number 1 or 2, or press X to exit.
Welcome to the Association! Please make a selection from the menu:
1. Explore the teams.
2. Arrange a new season.
X. Exit the system.
Enter a choice: X
Done
```

Comment: There is no method called `nextChar()`. Hope you know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void associationMenu(){
    char choice = readChoice();
    while (choice  != 'X' ){
        switch (choice) {
            case '1': exploreTeams(); break;
            case '2': newSeason(); break;
            // changed here
            default: System.out.println("Please enter a number 1 or 2, or press X to exit."); break;
        }

        choice = readChoice();  // changed here
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

I have changed the code in 2 places and commented on them.

Note that you need to take the choice inside the `while loop` otherwise If you give input as `1` or `2` it will run on an infinite `loop`.

I added a print statement to the `default` part for display `"Please enter a number 1 or 2, or press X to exit."` only if the input is not equal to `1`, `2`, or `X`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood assignment properly then you can modify readChoice() method like:

```
public char readChoice() {
    associationMenuHelp();
    System.out.print("Enter a choice: ");
    char choice = In.nextChar();
    while (choice != '1' && choice != '2' && choice != 'X') {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number 1 or 2, or press X to exit.");
        System.out.print("Enter a choice: ");
        choice = In.nextChar();
    }
    return choice;
}
```

In this modified method when the user does not put a '1' '2' or 'X' then the loop will print what you want. Also, you can remove the default statement in assoationMenu() after this modification

Comment: thanks heaps, this works like a charm. Would I have to keep adding more conditionals in the while loop if there are more cases in the associationMenu ?

Comment: Yep. You will need to add more conditionals to your cases. But if you do not want to have a lot of conditionals then you can create an array with your characters and then in for loop just compare them to 'choice'. Hopefully, it`s all clear to you. Feel free to ask other questions and don't forget to close this one.